# error en stored procedure: is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

Tags: mysql

Soy nuevo en MySQL e intento hacer un stored procedure para hacer un login en vb.net

Pero al querer crearlo me manda el error

> "@u" is not valid at this position, expecting an identifier

El Stores es

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_login` (@u varchar(50), @p varchar(100))
As
DECLARE @ap varchar(50)
BEGIN
SELECT @ap=passwd FROM transportesclaudia.usuarios WHERE login=@u

IF @ap IS NULL
RETURN -1
ELSE
IF @ap=@p
RETURN 1
ELSE
RETURN -2

END
```

Answer (score 1):

- Primero me parece que estas mezclando sintaxis, ya que [si checas la doc. de SQL Server] verás que si ocupa el prefijo `@` para la declaración de los nombres de variables; mientras que por otro lado MySQL no lo requiere.
- La sintaxis de un condicional en MySQL es: `IF THEN ELSEIF THEN END IF`
- Me parece que MySQL no puede hacer `return` de un valor dentro de un PA, por lo tanto en cambio prueba con un `SELECT` para que al momento de que lo invoques

Prueba entonces tu PA de esta forma:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_login` (u varchar(50), p varchar(100))
    BEGIN
        DECLARE ap varchar(50);
        SELECT ap=passwd FROM transportesclaudia.usuarios WHERE login=u;

        IF ap IS NULL THEN
            SELECT -1;
        ELSEIF ap=p THEN
            SELECT 1;
        ELSE
            SELECT -2;
        END IF;
    END;
//
```

Comment: Ohhh muy bien, que bueno que me lo aclaraste, solo que me manda el error del DELIMITER dice que espera CREATE, he copiado tu codigo para ver si me había equivocado pero no... :/